# Why is my Ruby on Rails app creating nil objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

For my Ruby on Rails App, my random generator index view is supposed to show a table of all random generators. I am using Ruby version 1.9.2. Here is what my Migrate file looks like

```
class CreateRandomgenerators < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :randomgenerators do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :query
    end
  end
end
```

This is my **seed** file

```
Randomgenerator.create!({:title => 'Test', :query => 'Christ the Center'})
```

This is my **model**

```
class Randomgenerator < ActiveRecord::Base

 attr_accessor :title, :query

   def generate_verse
       table = Movie.where{self.query.include?(:rating) == true}
       verse = table[0]
       return verse
   end

end
```

and this is the **view**

```
%table#randomgenerators
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Title
      %th Run Generator
  %tbody
    - @randomgenerators.each do |randomgenerator|
      %tr
        %td= randomgenerator.title
        %td= link_to "Run #{randomgenerator.title}", randomgenerator_path(randomgenerator)
```

After seeding the database and running the app on WEBrick, this table is filled with "ghost records": the title field is blank, but the "Run" link still appears and takes me to the random generator page. However, when I try to delete it, it claims that I am trying to act upon a Nil class. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: thats the index or randomgeneratorcontroller?

Comment: Remove `title` from `attr_accessor` and try again.

Comment: There is not validation in your model, then why are you using create! method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `attr_accessor`! inheriting from activerecord::base automatically adds methods for the fields in the database.

---

Explanation:

Calling `attr_accessor :title` creates the methods `title=` and `title` which get and set the `@title` instance variable.

Instance variables of objects start out `nil` until they are set. From the problem description it sounds like nothing is showing up in the view (so it's probably returning `nil`).

Object-oriented inheritance allows methods defined on the child class to override methods defined on the parent class. `Randomgenerator < ActiveRecord::Base` means that `Randomgenerator` is a child class of `ActiveRecord::Base`.

ActiveRecord would have gotten the value correctly based on the table structure and data available. However, all of that functionality was overriden, and calling `title` returns `@title` which is `nil`.

Comment: That definitely solved the problem with the index view and the update action, but when I click the "Run generator" link to view the generator's page, the tile for the random generator is blank, and it claims these objects to be nil objects when I attempt to create or destroy them.

Comment: I solved these other problems on my own. I was accidentally trying to delete the wrong instance variable when deleting, and I realized that I was accidentally "creating" just the tile of randomgenerator when I should be creating the object itself. Thanks for the help, you guys!